# golang net.LookupIP fails with connection refused

Tags: go

Call to `net.LookupIP("server.example.com")` results in error:

`lookup server.example.com on [::1]:53: read udp [::1]:39828->[::1]:53: read: connection refused`

```
ips, err := net.LookupIP(host)
```

However `nslookup server.example.com` works fine on the same server.

Any pointers to debug this?

Comment: How is the dns server configured on your machine?

Comment: Your host dns config points to `[::1]:53` but there is no server there

Comment: I just updated the question with the fact that nslookup works fine